# Kobolds and Catacombs solo adventure loading extremely slowly

Tags: hearthstone

Whenever I want to play a solo Kobolds and Catacombs game, the game shuffles through 30 or 40 of the loading boxes (Blaming the Rogue, Polishing Mana Crystals etc.)

Is this intentional? Does this happen to everyone? Or is it the fault of my client?

MacBook Pro 13", 2016, macOS High Sierra 10.13.1.

Comment: You're not listing any of the other hardware information, CPU speed, RAM, video card, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was only temporary, caused by server lag.

Kobolds and Catacombs was only a few minutes old when I started playing it, and too many other people were, too, so the server couldn't handle it and was extremely slow.